# swift - game countdown timer almost working

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I'm using script (below), to use as a countdown for my game start, the script I've used is from Gourav Nayyar's YouTube video and works great for the first time it is called.  However once the game goes through the reset process and the script is called again I only see `5` rather than `5 - 4 - 3 - 2 - 1 - GO!`.  If I remove one of the cals from my script then it works fine either in the reset func or when `gameScene` loads.

Here is the two calls in `GameScene.swift`

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    var gamelaunchTimerView:TimerView = TimerView.loadingCountDownTimerViewInView(self.view!)
    gamelaunchTimerView.startTimer()

func resetScene() {

    //code removed from here
    return countdown()

}

func countdown() {
    var gamelaunchTimerView:TimerView = TimerView.loadingCountDownTimerViewInView(self.view!)
    gamelaunchTimerView.startTimer()

}
```

Here is the Timer Code in `GameLaunchTimer.swift` as this is set up the countdown only works when first called and hangs on the second call.

```
//
//  TimerView.swift
//  GameLaunchTimer
//
//  Created by Gourav Nayyar on 7/3/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Gourav Nayyar. All rights reserved.
//

let VIEW_ALPHA:CGFloat = 0.5
let TIMERVIEW_RADIUS:CGFloat = 50
let TIMER_LABEL_INITIAL_VAL:Int =  5
let BORDER_WIDTH:CGFloat = 2
var timerVal:Int = TIMER_LABEL_INITIAL_VAL;
var timer:NSTimer!


import UIKit
import QuartzCore

class TimerView :UIView {

struct Stored {
static var timerLbl:UILabel!
}


class func loadingCountDownTimerViewInView (_superView:UIView)-> TimerView
{
var timerView:TimerView = TimerView(frame:_superView.frame)
//   timerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(VIEW_ALPHA)
_superView.addSubview(timerView)

/* add a custom Circle view */

let refFrame:CGRect = CGRectMake(_superView.center.x-TIMERVIEW_RADIUS, _superView.center.y-TIMERVIEW_RADIUS, 2*TIMERVIEW_RADIUS, 2*TIMERVIEW_RADIUS)
var circleView:UIView = UIView(frame:refFrame)
circleView.layer.cornerRadius = TIMERVIEW_RADIUS
circleView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
circleView.layer.borderWidth = BORDER_WIDTH

/* add a custom Label */

Stored.timerLbl = UILabel(frame:circleView.bounds)
Stored.timerLbl.text = "\(TIMER_LABEL_INITIAL_VAL)"
Stored.timerLbl.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
Stored.timerLbl.font = UIFont(name: "MarkerFelt-Thin", size: 40)
Stored.timerLbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

circleView.addSubview(Stored.timerLbl)
timerView.addSubview(circleView)

return timerView
}

func startTimer()
{
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0
  , target: self, selector: Selector("updateTimer:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func updateTimer(dt:NSTimer)
{
timerVal--
if timerVal==0{
  Stored.timerLbl.text = "GO!"
}else if timerVal<0{
  timer.invalidate()
  removeCountDownTimerView()
} else{
  Stored.timerLbl.text = "\(timerVal)"
}
}

func removeCountDownTimerView()
{
var mySuperView:UIView = self.superview!
mySuperView.userInteractionEnabled = true
super.removeFromSuperview()
}
}
```

Comment: your code is working fine If you remove what (one of the cals...?)?

Comment: @Shoaib that's right. When I remove one call the count down works perfectly, with both calls only one countdown works perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your variables under the class body;

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

class TimerView :UIView {

let VIEW_ALPHA:CGFloat = 0.5
let TIMERVIEW_RADIUS:CGFloat = 50
let TIMER_LABEL_INITIAL_VAL:Int =  5
let BORDER_WIDTH:CGFloat = 2
var timerVal:Int = TIMER_LABEL_INITIAL_VAL;
var timer:NSTimer!

... // other code
```

or, may be

```
    let VIEW_ALPHA:CGFloat = 0.5
    let TIMERVIEW_RADIUS:CGFloat = 50
    let TIMER_LABEL_INITIAL_VAL:Int =  5
    let BORDER_WIDTH:CGFloat = 2

    import UIKit
    import QuartzCore

    class TimerView :UIView {

    var timerVal:Int = TIMER_LABEL_INITIAL_VAL;
    var timer:NSTimer!
    ... //other code
```

Comment: Uppercase is generally not used with constants in Swift.

Comment: @Shoaib thank you so much, the second script worked just by moving `timerVal` and `NSTimer`.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Assign nil to the timer after invalidating it: even though you are invalidating, the object state is still kept, resulting on states conflicts when creating a new instance of the timer, once that it runs in a different thread.